# Amazon IAM permissions limit S3FullAccess permission to one bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am new to Amazon IAM permissions. I created a group, added some users and then added a Policy, the one I found that suited me the most is called `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy, but I want to grant the group full access permission only to one of my buckets, not to all of them, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `AmazonS3FullAccess` looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

In IAM Policies, things like buckets are identified by the element "[Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Resource)."  You might notice the policy above specifies the resource as the wildcard character `*`. This means that the policy above applies to all S3 resources.

You can limit the policy to a single S3 bucket by specifying the [ARN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) of the bucket you wish to use:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET-NAME"
```

**Related:**

- [AWS Documentation - IAM Policy Elements Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html)
- [AWS Documentation - S3 Bucket ARN Syntax](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-s3)